# On click interraction between screens android

Tags: android

I have created 2 main activity.java files in my source file.
In the first one i make the first screen appear and when i click a button i want to go
to another activity in order to get the second screen appear.
That's why i have created my MainActivity2.java file that is triggered when i click a button.

Although i have no compile errors, when i run my app it stops in the simulator and it does not even show the first screen. The code is the following :

MainActivity.java  :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button imageButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        imageButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }


}
```

and for

MainActivity2.java  :

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

   @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_2);
    }


   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

}

, where activity_main is my first .xml file containing the forst screen and imageButton1 is
the button i have created in my xml file that i want to go to the MainActivity2, when clicked  and trigger the second activity in order to show the second screen. And activity_main_2.xml contains the second screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, have you declared both of the activities in the manifest file of the application? That might be the reason why the application force closes.

Secondly,
In the onClick method you should check if that button has ***actually been clicked*** by checking for the id of the button.

public void onClick(View v) {

```
if(v.getId()==R.id._idofImageButton_){
     Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
     startActivity(i);
}
```

}

Hope this helps.

Comment: He shouldn't check, because he set imageButton1.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: As he is using a top level click listener, it is good practice to check, in case he wants to add additional buttons in future.  The suggestion seems good to me.

Comment: IMHO, it's a bad practice to use top level click listener at all. But question not about that.

Comment: Both my MainActivities are declared in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: @app_dev You should show the stack trace you got so that we can check for the error's exact location. There appears to be no other obvious error in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if you have added second Activity to AndroidManifest file. If you did, then please, provide stack trace.

Comment: My MainActivity2 is declared in the AndroidManifest.xml as this :

Comment: My MainActivity2 is declared in the AndroidManifest.xml as this :      <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity2"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>

Comment: Then i don't know if the things are ok as concerns the button Since i have declared imageButton2 alrready in my activity_main.xml and the image is loaded an then again i create a button with th same name (imageButton2) in the MainActivity.java

Comment: Provide stack trace please. You can found it in LOG-cat

Comment: Could somebody explain what exactly whould be the problem?

Comment: With information that you have provided - no. You should show us stacktrace.

Comment: but i want to know if there is any obvious mistake in the code i just have posted above..